# Why the section div's heading is shifting left when the nav bar is getting sticky after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having strange problem here.I have designed a sticky nav bar and sticky sidebar,which sticks at top after some scrolling of page.But i am not able to figure out the problem with the section div's heading behaviour .When the scroll threshold is reached the heading shifts left of the section.Its happening at the same time when nav bar and sidebar are getting fixed at top.And why the hell heading is not at left as it is supposed to be in normal condition?
Please help me out.

I am having trouble to add code snippet so i am pasting all code here.

**HTML**

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>

          <head><title>home</title>
          <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
          <meta charset="utf-8">
             <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="java/script.js"></script>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-             scale=1.0">

          <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
       </head>


       <body>

               <div class="header">
               <img class="header" src="images/top.jpg" alt="journal of advance science & environment" />

               </div>
         <nav class="nv" id="respNav">

                 <a class="resp" href="#">Home</a>
                 <a class="resp" href="#">Aims and Scope</a>
                 <a class="resp" href="#">Editorial Board</a>
                 <a class="resp" href="#">Author's guidelines</a>
                 <a class="resp" href="#">Contact us</a>
                 <a id="icon" href="#">Menu</a> 


            </nav>  

       <div class="sidebar">

                 <h2 class="sidebar">Quick Links</h2>
                 <ul class="sidebar">
                 <li>dummy grgree </li>
                 <li>dummyummy </li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummyssfs</li>
                 <li>dummysfsf</li>
                 <li>dummysfsf</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummysfsf</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummyddwe</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummyzzzz</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy33333</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy</li>
                 <li>dummy third last</li>
                 <li>dummy sec last</li>
                 <li>dummy last</li>


                 </ul>




            </div>
         <div class="section">
         <h1>heading</h1>


         </div>

      <!--  <script>
        function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("respNav");
       if (x.className === "nv") {
         x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
             x.className = "nv";
          }
       }
       </script>-->


     </body>


     </html>
```

**CSS**

```
          *{box-sizing:border-box}
         body{margin:0}
       /*=================================================================
                     HEADER
       ===================================================================*/

        div.header{margin:0;
       padding:0;
       max-width:100%;
       height:auto;
       background-color:black;

       }

       img.header{width:100%;
       display:block;
       }

       nav.fixed{position:fixed;
                top:0;width:100%;
                z-index:10
            }

        nav{background-color:#e3a836;
        border-bottom:2px solid #00384d;
        border-top:2px solid #00384d;
          z-index:10
         }


        nav a{display:inline-block;
        text-decoration:none;
         color:white;
       font-size:20px;
       font-family: calibri;
       padding:15px 25px;
        letter-spacing:2px;
        margin:0;
        margin-right:-4px;
       transition-duration: 0.4s;
        }

          nav.nv a#icon{display:none;}                             

       nav a:hover{background-color:#00384d;

        }      

         div.sidebar{
                   width:200px;
                  float:left;
                  height:650px; 
                  background:#00384d;
                  padding:5px;
                  overflow-y:scroll;
                  }

             h2.sidebar{
                        padding:0 20px;
                        margin-left:-4px;
                        margin-right:-4px;
                        background:#e3a836;
                        }


                   ul.sidebar{list-style-type:none;
                              padding:0 0 0 0;
                              margin:0 0 50px 0;
                              } 
                 ul.sidebar li{margin:5px -4px 5px -4px;  
                  font-size:18px;
                 padding:0 5px 0 10px;
                  color:white;
                      }
        ul.sidebar li:nth-child(odd){background:#004761}

         div.sidebarFixed{
                         position:fixed;
                         top:48px;
                        }   

           div.section{width:65%;
                      position:relative;
                    left:300px;
                    top:50px;
                   height:2000px;
                  background:#f2f2f2;
                    }           












               /*=====================================================
                                 MEDIA SCREEN
                             ===============*/
           @media only screen and (max-width: 800px){

         nav.nv {width:100%;z-index:10;border-top:2px solid red;border-                bottom:2px solid green;}
          nav.nv a.resp{display: none;}
            nav.nv a#icon{display:inline-block;
              width:100%;
              }

          nav.nv.responsive a{display:block;}



            }
```

**JavaScript**

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){

             var navOffset=jQuery("nav").offset().top;
             jQuery("nav").wrap('<div class="placeholder" ></div>');
              jQuery("div.placeholder").height(jQuery("nav").outerHeight());




            jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

            var scrollPos=jQuery(window).scrollTop();

            if(scrollPos >= navOffset){

            jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");            
            jQuery(".sidebar").addClass("sidebarFixed");

         }else{
                jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
                jQuery(".sidebar").removeClass("sidebarFixed");
                }

            }); 
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you used an unnecessary `position: fixed;` style to the `div.sidebarFixed` class. Remove that style, and the header remains in position.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25312/

Try using this instead:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="java/script.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>


<body>

  <div class="header">
    <img class="header" src="images/top.jpg" alt="journal of advance science & environment" />

  </div>
  <nav class="nv" id="respNav">

    <a class="resp" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="resp" href="#">Aims and Scope</a>
    <a class="resp" href="#">Editorial Board</a>
    <a class="resp" href="#">Author's guidelines</a>
    <a class="resp" href="#">Contact us</a>
    <a id="icon" href="#">Menu</a>


  </nav>

  <div class="sidebar">

    <h2 class="sidebar">Quick Links</h2>
    <ul class="sidebar">
      <li>dummy grgree </li>
      <li>dummyummy </li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummyssfs</li>
      <li>dummysfsf</li>
      <li>dummysfsf</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummysfsf</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummyddwe</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummyzzzz</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy33333</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy</li>
      <li>dummy third last</li>
      <li>dummy sec last</li>
      <li>dummy last</li>


    </ul>




  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <h1>heading</h1>


  </div>

  <!--  <script>
        function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("respNav");
       if (x.className === "nv") {
         x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
             x.className = "nv";
          }
       }
       </script>-->


</body>


</html>
```

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      var navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;
      jQuery("nav").wrap('<div class="placeholder" ></div>');
      jQuery("div.placeholder").height(jQuery("nav").outerHeight());




      jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

        var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {

          jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
          jQuery(".sidebar").addClass("sidebarFixed");

        } else {
          jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
          jQuery(".sidebar").removeClass("sidebarFixed");
        }

      });
    })
```

```
     * {
       box-sizing: border-box
     }

     body {
       margin: 0
     }
     /*=================================================================
                 HEADER
   ===================================================================*/

     div.header {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       max-width: 100%;
       height: auto;
       background-color: black;
     }

     img.header {
       width: 100%;
       display: block;
     }

     nav.fixed {
       position: fixed;
       top: 0;
       width: 100%;
       z-index: 10
     }

     nav {
       background-color: #e3a836;
       border-bottom: 2px solid #00384d;
       border-top: 2px solid #00384d;
       z-index: 10
     }

     nav a {
       display: inline-block;
       text-decoration: none;
       color: white;
       font-size: 20px;
       font-family: calibri;
       padding: 15px 25px;
       letter-spacing: 2px;
       margin: 0;
       margin-right: -4px;
       transition-duration: 0.4s;
     }

     nav.nv a#icon {
       display: none;
     }

     nav a:hover {
       background-color: #00384d;
     }

     div.sidebar {
       width: 200px;
       float: left;
       height: 650px;
       background: #00384d;
       padding: 5px;
       overflow-y: scroll;
     }

     h2.sidebar {
       padding: 0 20px;
       margin-left: -4px;
       margin-right: -4px;
       background: #e3a836;
     }

     ul.sidebar {
       list-style-type: none;
       padding: 0 0 0 0;
       margin: 0 0 50px 0;
     }

     ul.sidebar li {
       margin: 5px -4px 5px -4px;
       font-size: 18px;
       padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
       color: white;
     }

     ul.sidebar li:nth-child(odd) {
       background: #004761
     }

     div.sidebarFixed {
       top: 48px;
     }

     div.section {
       width: 65%;
       position: relative;
       left: 300px;
       top: 50px;
       height: 2000px;
       background: #f2f2f2;
     }
     /*=====================================================
                             MEDIA SCREEN
                         ===============*/

     @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
       nav.nv {
         width: 100%;
         z-index: 10;
         border-top: 2px solid red;
         border- bottom: 2px solid green;
       }
       nav.nv a.resp {
         display: none;
       }
       nav.nv a#icon {
         display: inline-block;
         width: 100%;
       }
       nav.nv.responsive a {
         display: block;
       }
     }
```